# Screen covered with gray stripes

Tags: display, troubleshooting, lenovo-laptop

I have a new Lenovo laptop, Yoga 520, running under Windows 10.

Every now and then, the screen gets covered with gray vertical stripes, fully or partially (whole height but not whole width). So far we have not seen a correlation with movements, shocks on the device or specific Windows usage. The kind of stripes is like the picture below. Usually, rebooting the machine works for a while.

Two questions:

- Has anyone had this problem on a similar laptop ?
- Could it be a software rather than hardware problem ?

(To make things easier, the laptop is in the hands of my young daughter, 8000 kms away.)

[image: Stripes]

Sorry if I am not on the right site (please recommend).

Comment: this looks like a hardware issue.  is it still under warranty?

Comment: @Keltari: it is. But I want to make sure before, as we will need the PC shipped back here, I am afraid.

Comment: Definitely would send it back under warranty. It could be a ribbon cable that is a bit loose. Warmth can expand and contract the ribbon cable making these kinds of issues. Then again, a reboot would not fix that. Could be a malfunctioning GPU too.... but this is still speculating and the fact that you can't test anything because the device is far away makes it kind of hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: @LPChip: absolutely. We will try to plug an external screen.

Comment: +1 on hardware issues. Don’t even take a chance on this. If it’s within the return period for the store take it back immediately for a refund. Buy a different one. If not, get the warranty process started. Why can’t your daughter ship it in directly for repair?

Comment: @Appleoddity: she can but I don't want to afford a double shipping if unnecessary. Will cost us an arm.

Comment: Most warranties I'm familiar with cover shipping.

Comment: @music2myear: mh, shipping back, not shipping to. But I'll ask them.